# Limit with abs $\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{|\tan(-2x)|}{\arcsin(-5x)}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

It there any rule about abs limits? Thanks
NO use L'Hopital, no derivate

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{|\tan(-2x)|}{\arcsin(-5x)}}$$

Comment: What have you tried so far on this one ? Please share your work. Also, what's the sign of $\tan(x),x\to0,x<0$ ? Knowing this, you can get rid of the abs value.

Comment: I tried this but i don't think it is good
$$=\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{-(\tan(-2x))}{\arcsin(-5x)}*\frac{-5x}{-5x}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{-2x}{\cos(0)*(-5x)}} =\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you go from your first line to the second (I'm not saying it's false), but __your result is true__. I'll post a quick answers for others who might be wondering how to get it.

Comment: $$=\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{arcsin(x)}{x}} = 1 $$ i use this but i dont know if it is true

Comment: It is true. You can prove it by l'Hopital's rule, but according to your question you're not allowed to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $$|x|=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
x,& x\geq 0\\
-x,& x<0\end{array} \right.$$
When we use the limit we have to consider the left and right limit of the point(s) in which the abs. value is zero, in this case it is for $x=0$, and we have that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-}|x|=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} (-x) \; \; \text{and} \; \;\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}|x|=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} x$$

For your problem, you get.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \frac{|\tan (-2x)|}{\arcsin (-5x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \frac{-\tan (-2x)}{\arcsin (-5x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \frac{\tan (2x)}{\arcsin (-5x)}=\left\{\begin{array}{c} 
x=0-\varepsilon\\
\varepsilon >0 \\
\varepsilon \rightarrow 0\end{array} \right\}=\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan (-2\varepsilon)}{\arcsin (5\varepsilon)}$$
$$=-\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan (2\varepsilon)}{\arcsin (5\varepsilon)}=-\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(2\varepsilon)}{\cos (2\varepsilon) \arcsin (5\varepsilon)}=\left\{\begin{array}{c} 
\sin x\sim x,\; \arcsin x\sim x\\x \rightarrow 0\end{array} \right\}=-\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\varepsilon}{\cos (2\varepsilon) 5\varepsilon}=-\frac{2}{5}$$

Comment: Using $\sin(x)\sim x$ is using Taylor series, which is even more powerful than l'Hopital's rule. I don't think this would fit the OP's criterion.

Comment: It can be easily proven that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ using a proof with triangle similarity.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I suppose there's a similar way for $\arcsin(x)\sim x$  ?

Comment: We can say that $x=sin(u)$, then $arcsin(sin(u))\sim \sin(u) \Leftrightarrow  u\sim \sin u$

Answer (score 1):

For $x\to0,x<0$, $\tan(-2x)>0$ hence $\frac{|\tan(-2x)|}{\arcsin(-5x)}=\frac{\tan(2x)}{\arcsin(5x)}=\frac{\sin(2x)}{\arcsin(5x)}\frac{1}{\cos(2x)}$

Thus $\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{|\tan(-2x)|}{\arcsin(-5x)}}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\arcsin(5x)}\frac{1}{\cos(0)}$

By l'Hopital (PS : I forgot you didn't want to use l'Hopital's rule, I'll edit this - Edit : see zemelovac's answer, there's no need for the rule to solve the following limit) , $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\arcsin(5x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2}5\sqrt{1-25x^2}\cos(2x)=\frac{2}5$

Thus $\boxed{\lim_{x\to0^-}{\frac{|\tan(-2x)|}{\arcsin(-5x)}}=\frac{2}5}$